# Correlation between text elements frequency in dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

Trying to find correlation between items, which are structured into one row of a dataset. Want to find the correlation of frequency between sets of items.

I have to admit I'm completely lost, and I have tried googling to find solutions for almost 6 hrs as of now.

Have tried to illustrate the data below:

```
#create a table
data = {'Customer': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Order': ['1 Hamburger, 1 Soda',
              '1 Soda, 1 Hamburger,  1 Fries',
              '1 Pizza, 2 Soda',
              '1 Soda, 1 Ice Cream']}
```

Table:

```
   Customer Order
0   1       1 Hamburger, 1 Soda
1   2       1 Soda, 1 Hamburger, 1 Fries
2   3       1 Pizza, 2 Soda
3   4       1 Soda, 1 Ice Cream
```

So here we can see that the items in the order column is not seperated.
So I split them by their comma seperator.

```
new = df["Order"].str.split(",", n = -1, expand = True) 
new.columns.astype('str')
new.rename(columns=lambda x: 'Item'+str(x), inplace=True)
```

After splitting items in the order column, I have removed the number in front of the items, with this:

```
for i in list(new):
new[i] = new[i].map(lambda x: x.lstrip()[1:] if x is not None else None)
```

Which returns this table:

```
    Item0     Item1       Item2
0   Hamburger Soda        None
1   Soda      Hamburger   Fries
2   Pizza     Soda        None
3   Soda      Ice Cream   None
```

So far so good (I think), now here comes the problem.

I want to see how often e.g. Hamburger and Soda is bought together.
Which in returns means I can look at the correlation between items, so I can see how Hamburger and Fries correlate for example.

So far I'm thinking a solution could be something like this (Had to make the table manually, as I didn't find a way to do it in Pandas):

```
example = {'Hamburger': [1,1,0,0],
          'Soda': [1,1,1,1],
          'Pizza': [0,0,1,0],
          'Fries': [0,1,0,0],
          'Ice Cream': [0,0,0,1]}


    Hamburger   Soda    Pizza   Fries   Ice Cream
0   1           1       0       0       0
1   1           1       0       1       0
2   0           1       1       0       0
3   0           1       0       0       1
```

Is there a good way to show the correlation of items?

Do I need to convert it into e.g. 0 and 1 like I did in the table above, if so, what would be the best way if let's say the dataset was 1 million rows?

I'm also worried about the effect of having uneven amount of items per row, will the result be skewed by the differences in the rows?

For example in the table above Hamburger and Soda are in row 1, while in row 2 it is also including a Fries, how does that affect the correlation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to make that table is to do:

```
pd.get_dummies(your_table)
```

For getting correlation, you do:

```
your_table.corr()
```

To plot your correlation, you do:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(your_table.corr())
```

If a customer buys hamburger with soda and fries most of the times, then the person will have high correlation between hamburger, soda and hamburger, fries. If there are less fries with hamburger and more sodas, then soda will have a high correlation.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect! The only thing I need to figure out to make it complete is how to merge item0_Hamburger with item1_Hamburger, due to the random order of items in the table.